# "Immutable" interfaces

Tags: design, object-oriented, naming, interfaces, immutability

I am confused about the notion of immutability. Consider the following structure of a simplistic calculator:

[image: Class diagram]

Here are the interfaces:

```
interface IOperationalInterface {
    int Sum(int a, int b);
}

interface IAuditInterface {
    int SumInvocations();
}
```

`IOperationalInterface.Sum` should compute the sum of two integers and `IAuditInterface.SumInvocations` should return the total number of received `Sum` calls.

Here is a trivial implementation:

```
class CalculatorImpl : IOperationalInterface, IAuditInterface {
    private int invocations = 0;

    public int Sum(int a, int b) {
        invocations++;
        return a + b;
    }

    public int SumInvocations() {
        return invocations;
    }
}
```

Is `CalculatorImpl` immutable? Obviously not, because its state changes with each invocation of the `Sum` method. Is the `Sum` operation pure? According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) it is not, since it changes the state of a mutable object, and that side-effect is observable through the `IAuditInterface`. Obviously the `SumInvocations` operation is also not pure, since it may return different results.

In summary, `CalculatorImpl` is mutable and all of its methods are impure.

However, from the viewpoint of `CalculatorClient`, who talks to it only through the `IOperationalInterface`, it appears to be immutable and the `Sum` operation appears to be pure in the sense that it could not observe any side effects *through that interface*.

On the other hand, from the perspective of `AuditClient`, it is completely different: it is obvious that the object implementing the `AuditInterface` is mutable and its `SumInvocations` operation is impure, and *this follows directly from the specification of the `IAuditInterface`*.

So, it is possible to partition an interface/specification of a mutable class such that some parts of it will appear mutable and some not. In this case, considering only the `Sum` operation and leaving out the requirement that the invocations should be counted, we get something that does not have any side-effects.

Now, on implementing the `CalculatorClient` one can take into account the fact that the object behind the interface *appears* to be immutable. At least one could not tell the difference.

So my question is: does it make sense to talk about "immutability" of interfaces or is it a bad idea? How else can I communicate the fact that there will be no observable side-effects through that interface? And if it's bad, what could go wrong?

**UPDATE**

Thanks for your answers/comments! I see now that there is no way to say that the `IOperationalInterface` is pure; the conditions of purity are much too strong to apply in this case. However the question remains whether there is a weaker notion (maybe "immutability"?) which is applicable.

Comment: I don't want to copy/paste the whole answer, so: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7540563/319403

Comment: Ok, there's no such thing as an "immutable" interface. But you still could differentiate between a "no-observable-side-effects" interface and a "regular" one?

Comment: IMO, no, and for the same reason.  The "no-observable-side-effects" part can't be guaranteed or enforced while inheritance is allowed.  And with an interface, inheritance is basically *required*.

Comment: The distinction for no /observable/ side effects is mostly for things like logging, caching, lazy eval, et cetera. Read observable as "functional"--as in, if you removed them, the program's correctness would not change. In this case, your side effects are behavioral and your function is impure.

Comment: @cHao What do you mean by "enforced"? Proven formally? Then that can't be guaranteed even if inhericance is *not* allowed.

Comment: @proskor: What i mean is that if i have a class Thing that promises not to do something, i can prohibit inheritance to ensure that all Things uphold that promise.  The instant i allow inheritance, though, that promise is invalid -- there's no telling what a subclass will do, and off the top of my head, i can't think of a language that lets you specify such a restriction.  Even languages with "code contracts" would have trouble enforcing it.

Comment: Leaving aside the interface aspect, `Sum()` as written is vulnerable to a race condition.

Comment: @cHao So you consider the class' implementation as actually being its specification. Say, the class promises what it implements. Ok, but that means that the only way to specify something is to actually implement it, which is, well, missing the point of specification.

Comment: @proskor: I believe that interfaces can specify what a subclass *must* do, and any deviation from that is an error on the subclass's part.  But they can't make any promises about what a subclass *will not* do.  If you can reframe "no observable side effects" as a specific, positive requirement (like, say, "Given two arbitrary ints `a` and `b`, any two invocations of `Sum(a, b)` must return the same value"), that's valid.  But "this method must not have any observable side effects" is invalid, IMO.

Comment: @cHao Good point. However, I think that an "immutable" interface is not the same as an interface in which all operations are pure functions. Instead, I suggest that an "immutable" interface is an interface whose specification contains no state. But I am not sure if that's correct.

Comment: @cHao There's no way to force classes to return the sum of `a` and `b` when they implement `Sum`, so how is requiring purity any harder than requiring the correct semantics? Both are impossible to enforce but code will be written as if they were.

Comment: @Doval: Note that my example requires neither purity nor even a definition of "sum".  All it requires is that the "sum" be the same each time, *as far as a consumer of the interface is concerned*.  The problem with requiring true purity in an interface is that it is not reasonable -- it crosses the line between inheritance and implementation.  If you already know exactly what `Sum` must return, and that it must not do anything else, then why have an interface in the first place?  Just define a class and be done with it.

Comment: @cHao You haven't given any real justification for why it's not reasonable. I expect `List.add` to terminate, and to *not throw any exceptions not listed*. I also expect `List` to support `O(1)` access. Why can't I expect purity from an interface?

Comment: @cHao Why does a purity requirement cross "the line between implementation and inheritance"? What is that anyway?

Comment: Requiring purity is basically saying "after this call, nothing in the system will have apparently changed".  The interface would be overstepping its bounds to make rules about properties that it can't reasonably define.

Comment: @proskor: To require consistency is reasonable.  Purity is another matter.  A pure function has no visible side effects -- and "visible" doesn't just mean "visible through the interface".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However, from the viewpoint of CalculatorClient, who talks to it only through the IOperationalInterface, it appears to be immutable and the Sum operation appears to be pure in the sense that it could not observe any side effects *through that interface*.

Whatever you can observe through the interface is irrelevant to the concept of purity. If `Sum` logged results to a file, it would still be impure even though you wouldn't be able to observe any changes through the interface.

Purity is a very strong condition. If you say that something is pure, I'll take you at your word and assume nothing bad will happen if I run it from multiple threads, cache the results and only call it once for any given set of inputs, or that I can call it 1,000,000 times without exhausting the OS's file handles. Those assumptions can backfire when using `CalculatorImpl`.

There's nothing wrong with partitioning the interfaces the way you have, but you should be precise. The specification you want for `IOperationalInterface` is probably closer to: "The return value of these methods must depend only on their arguments, but their execution may have side effects." You can be more specific about the side effects and say that the methods must not perform any kind of I/O. But I wouldn't say that it's pure, because you're very clearly not using it that way.

Comment: Ok, then maybe there is a weaker notion than purity? For example, something like "the operations always return the same result for the same arguments and the order of invocations does not matter"?

Comment: @proskor Yeah, that sounds much better. There's probably no *name* for that concept but that's fine. You might want to specify whether the *number* of invocations matters though. Will something break if I decide to cache the results?

Comment: @proskor There is, it is called [Determinism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_algorithm). You can say `IOperationalInterface` is Deterministic.

Comment: @RMalke Good idea, but aren't all functions deterministic (except, maybe, random number generators and IO)?

Comment: @RMalke: Does "deterministic" have a useful meaning here?  I was thinking about that word, but one could quite convincingly argue that the object itself is also part of the function's input (and, particularly since it's modified, output).

Answer (score 4):

You're sort of getting hung up on definitions without worrying about why you care if a function is pure or not.  A pure function gives more freedom to the caller at the expense of restrictions on the implementer.  A function with side effects gives more freedom to the implementer at the expense of restrictions on the caller.

Most everyone is familiar with the restrictions on the implementer of a pure function, but many are not familiar with the freedoms it grants the caller.  It frees the caller to cache results and not call the function a second time.  It frees the caller to create as many copies of the object as they want, perhaps on different threads or even different systems, to speed up a computation.  It frees the caller to not have to worry about keeping the object in scope, because they can always recreate an identical one later.

If you're not going to grant those types of freedoms to the caller, it does no good to label an interface immutable.  You're putting restrictions on the implementer without any commensurate benefits to the caller, so you may as well lift the implementer restrictions.

Comment: This is what I meant by saying that on implementing the CalculatorClient one can take into account the fact that the object behind the interface appears to be immutable. For example, assuming that the operational interface is "immutable", it is easier to make the client implementation thread-safe. However if the interface is "mutable", it is more difficult or even impossible. But again, the question is whether there is such thing as an "immutable" or "pure" interface.

Comment: But you can't take it into account, because it isn't really immutable, and isn't easier to make thread safe, because `invocations++` isn't guaranteed to be atomic, and you don't have the freedom to make and destroy copies at will, because you'll lose the count.  Something that appears to be immutable but really isn't is worse than not being immutable at all.

Comment: To explicitly answer your question, yes pure interfaces exist, at least as a gentleman's agreement if not enforced by compiler, but there's no such thing as a pure interface with an impure implementation.  As soon as you create a side effect, you would be breaking the contract of the pure interface and therefore technically no longer implementing it.

Comment: @proskor: The *appearance* of immutability doesn't do much at all for thread-safety, if the implementation actually has side effects.  Thread safety requires that mutations either not occur at all, or be done in such a way that concurrency can never cause the system's state to be incorrect.  (In your example, since `invocations++` is not atomic, two threads using a `CalculatorImpl` -- even if only as an `IOperationalInterface` -- can cause the count to be incorrect.)

Comment: @cHao Probably I should not have used the term *appearance*, since it caused confusion. I didn't mean to say that something looks like it is immutable, but actually isn't. What I meant is that it "appears as immutable" to the client, i.e. there is no way for the client to encounter a situation in which the object could have changed somehow, therefore it can assume that it is immutable.

Comment: @proskor: What you seem to want would probably be better described as "consistency" or "self-consistency".  "Immutable" and "pure" are strong words, not used lightly (and almost exclusively reserved for implementations).  The former applies to the whole object (not just the interface), and the latter makes promises about a function's (lack of) effects on any part of the entire system.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt: I wouldn't say that the existence of side effects necessarily negates the purity of an interface, *provided* that callers are free to treat the function as they would a pure function, and any code which would use the side effects is required to deal with any consequences resulting from that treatment.  For example, suppose an interface provides a function to return a non-zero immutable integer.  If each processor core had an independent hardware random number generator, then an implementation which would, if a field was zero, retrieve a non-zero random number and do an...

Comment: ...atomic compare-and-store to that initially-zero field, and then returned the field value (whether initially zero or not), such an implementation could be considered "pure" despite the fact that value would be fixed after the first invocation but not before, since any assumptions calling code would be entitied to make on the basis of purity would be valid *despite* the side-effects of the first invocation.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation is clearly not immutable, so let's talk about the "pureness" of the `Sum` function.

It can only make sense to talk about the implementation, not the interface.  For instance, what if I created a new implementation of the interface with this `Sum` implementation?

```
public int Sum(int a, int b) {
    invocations++;
    if(invocations >= 1000)
    {
        return a + b + 1;
    }
    return a + b;
}
```

The interface hasn't changed, but the method is no longer "pure".

In a purely technical sense, even your naïve implementation isn't pure because eventually `invocations` will overflow and you'll get an exception when you call `Sum` instead of the expected result.

Comment: This is not only impure, this is simply incorrect. The specification for `Sum` was that it should compute the sum of two integers, and this implementation cleary does not comply to it. The possible overflow is a technical implementation issue, it has nothing to do with the problem: it is possible to restrict the specification or change the implementation accordingly such that overflow does not occur.

Comment: @proskor - your example was just an example, as was mine.  Your comment about the contract of `Sum` is correct, but your comment about the overflow issue is not correct.  How can you have a `Sum` function with a contract that says you can only call it a certain number of times?  Some (n)th call will eventually throw an exception, so it's not a pure function (it won't give you the same result every time you call it).  At any rate, this is all about implementation, not interface, which is my point.

Comment: What I meant is that the count of invocations could overflow, i.e. after the (n)-th call it could be reset to 0 instead of throwing an exception. The `Sum` operation remains a pure function. But even that is a marginal issue.

Comment: @proskor - Ok, what if my implementation logged the `Sum` inputs and result to a file, and then I got some kind of out-of-space or file-not-found kind of exception?  Sure, I could wrap it in a `catch` block.  The point is that the purity of it depends entirely on the implementation.  I could actually make `SumInvocations()` pure by always returning `42`.  It wouldn't be correct, but neither would your implementation if used in a multi-threaded environment.  Again, it has nothing to do with the interface, only the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you want is a variant of [Design by Contract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract) (C# interfaces are a poor man's version of them). In C# it could be achieved via custom attributes and a static analyzer extension (e.g. for Roslyn or ReSharper):

```
[Pure] //This is just a sample name, not to be confused with System.Diagnostics.Contracts.PureAttribute
interface IOperationalInterface
{
    int Sum(int a, int b);
}
```

Your custom static analyzer extension would then check if implementation(s) are side-effect free across all the interface methods. This might get complicated depending on the level of guarantee you would like to achieve (e.g. simply checking there are no mutating operators used versus walking any method invocation chains).

If you find this approach viable for your scenario, then consider checking existing contract-related tools for .NET (non of them works well though):

JetBrains: http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Code_Annotation_Attributes.html
Microsoft: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts

Comment: Yes, this is what I had in mind, however I am not sure whether the notion of a "pure" or "immutable" interface is sound. There are opinions that this is not the case, but I am not convinced yet. :)

Comment: @proskor The concept is sound. Pure/immutable interface is an interface with an added contract of no side effects guarantee.